# Get sequence in original format in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I have defined a sequence like so:

```
<#assign seq = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]>
```

I can do: `<#list seq[0..] as i>${i}</#list>` which will generate an output of `ABCDE`

Is it possible to get the sequence back in the original format? I.e. `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]`

For reference, I am using this to first assign an empty sequence and then elements items into it. I want to get the full sequence at the end in the original sequence format because it will be part of a JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing specialized on that, but you can do this (not sure what escaping syntax you need though, so here I used JSON):

```
[<#list seq as it>"${it?json_string}"<#sep>, </#list>]
```

Comment: The first solution will return back everything as a single string. The second solution can be modified to give the required output:  `[<#list seq as it>"${it}"<#sep>, </#list>]`

Comment: Will make this the accepted if you can edit your answer :)

Comment: Indeed, I have forgotten that you also need quoting... edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will return back the original sequence format:

```
<#assign seq = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]>
[<#list seq[0..] as i><#if i?has_next>"${i}",<#else>"${i}"</#if></#list>]
```